# Close Pop-up and refresh parent window not working

Tags: javascript

All of a sudden my simple javascript code to close a pop-up and refresh the parent window stopped working in Google Chrome browsers on iPad and iPhone devices. It still works if we use the built in safari browser on the same devices.

Any reason why someone could see this a wouldn't work in chrome? And by not working I mean that the pop-up closes and the parent window doesn't refresh.

```
 <!---Close -Reload The Window --->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseWindow() {
            window.close();
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
        }
    </script>

            <a href="" onClick="javascript: return CloseWindow();">Signature Captured - Close Window</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping window.close() and window.opener.location.reload(true) round?

Comment: Yes. It then will attempt to refresh the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

you cant refresh page after close the window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseWindow() {   
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
```

---

another Type , I test it, it works. If you get the problem again, your browser may cause the problem.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseWindow() {
            window.close();
            window.opener.location = window.opener.window.location;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: When I have my javascript this way, it tries to refresh the popup.

Comment: Ok, after further testing, the script works as designed in Safari on iPad and iPhone devices, but not the google chrome browser on the same devices. I will update my original question.

Comment: is the popup's url a cross domain?

Comment: no, it is a page in the same web directory as the parent.

Comment: try this window.opener.location = window.opener.window.location

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you post the full code as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Using the code you posted, it will close the popup first and then never refresh the parent. I'm assuming that's because the java code is actually located within the popup page so once it's closed, obviously there is no other code to execute. If I swap the two lines around and have the window.close() positioned second, it will try to refresh the pop-up window first, and not attempt to close out the pop-up at all. Should this code be located on the parent instead? Also, this only behaves like this in Chrome, not safari.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this using something other than JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

we located this function in the main page and call it from the popup window and it works
we commented out this post - but i don't see any reference to the setTimeout we did.. so I decided to point this out and maybe it will help someone else

main page

```
function reloadPage() {
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' Chrome') > -1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload(true);
    }, 0);
 } else {
    location.reload(true);
 }
}
```

popup page

```
window.top.opener.reloadPage();
```